# GUI statistics calculator (binomial coefficient etc)?

Tags: software-recommendation, calculator, statistical

I would have expected this to be easy to find. But, no Ubuntu calculator applications seem to have *binomial coefficient function* built in.

I know I can just do the formula each time with factorial. But, it would be nice just to have it built into the calculator.

Answer (score 1):

- Open GNOME "Calculator".
- Enter the following as input: `nCr(n;r)=n!÷r!÷(n−r)!` (I recommend to copy and paste the code I provided.)
- You have now defined a new *function* with name `nCr`.
- You can use it like any predefined "Calculator" function. For example enter: `nCr(4;2)` to get the output of `6`.

---

Note that functions that are defined by a user are stored in a user configuration file and can be reused in future `gnome-calculator` invocations. The location for custom function definitions is:

```
~/.local/share/gnome-calculator/custom-functions
```

Answer (score 0):

Speedcrunch has the `ncr` function. Simply type `ncr(10,4)`.